# Ratio and proportion

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was solving some maths problems when I got this one. I tried it several times in different ways but i didn't get any solution

If(a + b): (b + c) : (c + a) = 6 : 7 :8 and a + b + c = 14, then find the value of c?

Options
A - 6
B - 8
C - 14
D - 7

Comment: "I tried it several times in different ways" Please describe these.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the ratios, just write : a + b = 6 X, b + c = 7 X, c +a = 8 X. Now, solve these three linear equations for a,b and c as a function of X. You should arrive to a = 7 X / 2, b = 5 X / 2, c = 9 X / 2. Now (a+b+c)=14; replace by the values obtained, this gives 21 X / 2 = 14, that is to say X = 4 / 3 and then a = 14 /3, b = 10 / 3 and c = 6.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{a+b}6=\frac{b+c}7=\frac{c+a}8=\frac{a+b+b+c+c+a}{6+7+8}=\frac{a+b+c}{10.5}$$

$$=\frac{a+b+c-(a+b)}{10.5-6}=\frac c{4.5}$$

$$=\frac{a+b+c-(b+c)}{10.5-7}=\frac a{3.5}$$

$$=\frac{a+b+c-(c+a)}{10.5-8}=\frac b{2.5}$$

Let $$\frac c{4.5}=\frac a{3.5}=\frac b{2.5}=d$$